# Add new comment once slidedown

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble to understand how to write that css code in jquery, I'm trying to write sample small wall scripts like facebook where people put comment and add new comment information inside of list of comments ..... inside of list of comments i wrote in css like this...

```
.comment_box{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 515px;
    height: auto;
    border: dashed #999 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 300px;
    top: 171px;
}

.comment_box ul{
 list-style:none;
 padding:0;
}

.comment_box ul li{
padding:.5em;
height:auto;clear:both;
padding-bottom:35px;
margin-bottom:20px;
border-bottom:#e6e6e6 solid 1px;color:#000;}
```

When person input the new comments, before to add new comments inside of wall, i want that list of comment (comment_box) to be slide down bofore add new comment on the top of first row...

how can i write that in jquery with css to slidedown that comment_box once entered new comment!

is this write like this **$(.button).css('.comment_box ul li);** is this correct!

Does any other website have sample where i can learn!

Comment: Please complete the tutorials at the [jQuery Learning Center](http://learn.jquery.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you prepend the newly added comment before the comment box?